# How do I access nested configuration values from my custom gradle extension?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, groovy, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a custom gradle plugin that needs to accept an arbitrary number of nested parameters from the buildscript.  Something like:

```
myPlugin{
    configObjects = [
        {
             name="objectA",
             value=5,
        },
        {
             name="objectB",
             value=9,
        }
    ]
}
```

...where the number of items in configObjects, and the the values inside them is defined in whatever buildscript is importing the plugin.

So in my plugin code, I create an extension...

```
val config = extensions.create("myPlugin", myPluginTaskConfiguration::class.java, project)

tasks {
    register<myPluginTask>("myPlugin") {
        configObjects= config.configObjects
    }
}
```

and a class defining the structure of the data received through the extension:

```
open class myPluginTaskConfiguration(project: Project) {
    @Input
    @Option(option="configObjects", description = "list of configObjects")
    var configObjects:List<ConfigObject>?=null
}
```

Gradle allows me to specify the outer type, but apparently not the inner members.  Running my plugin task I get the following error:

> class build_f42r2ugava4a351q5usw8u65g$_run_closure1$_closure5 cannot be cast to class com.myplugin.ConfigObject (build_f42r2ugava4a351q5usw8u65g$_run_closure1$_closure5 is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler$ScriptClassLoader @224ed88; com.myplugin.ConfigObject is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @72fe231e)

It's not clear to me what the type of the objects in the configObjects block is (well, apparently they're of type build_f42r2ugava4a351q5usw8u65g$_run_closure1$_closure5, but I don't think that's something I can use at author-time)

How can I take the list of items from my groovy buildscript, and convert them into typed objects in my plugin (preferably in a way that allows the IDE to provide suggestions/hints to users editing the buildscript)?

Comment: Have you tried with `[name: "objectA", ...]` (a Map not a Closure)?

Answer (score 1):

1. `@Input` and `@Option` are for **tasks**. From the looks of it, you are using them for **extensions**.
2. There is no need to need to pass in a `project` instance in the constructor of a `Task`. All `Task`s have a reference to the `Project` they belong to https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#getProject--

With that said, full working example in Kotlin would be:

```
open class MyPluginTaskConfiguration @Inject constructor(objects: ObjectFactory) {
    val configObjects: ListProperty<Map<*, *>> = objects.listProperty()
}

open class MyPluginTask : DefaultTask() {
    @Input
    @Option(option="configObjects", description = "list of configObjects")
    val configObjects: ListProperty<Map<*, *>> = project.objects.listProperty()

    @TaskAction
    fun printMessage() {
        configObjects.get().forEach {
            println("$it")
        }
    }
}

val config = extensions.create("myPlugin", MyPluginTaskConfiguration::class.java)

configure<MyPluginTaskConfiguration> {
    configObjects.set(listOf(
            mapOf<String, Any>(
                    "name" to "objectA",
                    "value" to 5
            ),
            mapOf<String, Any>(
                    "name" to "objectB",
                    "value" to 9
            )
    ))
}

tasks.register("myPlugin", MyPluginTask::class) {
    configObjects.set(config.configObjects)
}
```

Executing the above produces:

```
./gradlew myPlugin

> Task :myPlugin
{name=objectA, value=5}
{name=objectB, value=9}
```

Refer to below doc for more details:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly?  It looks like the configObjects are hardcoded inside the extension rather than being passed in through the extension.